# Замена параметров в файле из файла

Tags: python, linux, bash, txt

Всем привет. Есть файл param.txt вида:

```
PARAM1=value1
PARAM2=value2
```

И есть файл example.txt в котором нужно заменить параметры из файла param.txt
Файл вот такого вида:

```
 Some text to example. PARAM1, PARAM2
```

И соответственно в нём нужно заменить PARAM1 на value1 и PARAM2 на value2 соответственно.

Как это можно сделать средствами bash или Python?

Comment: `source param.txt; sed -e "s,PARAM1,$PARAM1,g; s,PARAM2,$PARAM2,g"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так на Python:

```
import re #используем регулярное выражение

f1 = open("Путь к файлу 1.txt", "r") #Поменяйте на путь к файлу 1
f2 = open("Путь к файлу 2.txt", "r") #Поменяйте на путь к файлу 2
rf1 = f1.read()
rf2 = f2.read()
f1.close()
f2.close()
regular1 = re.findall(r'PARAM1=(\S+)', rf1)[0] #PARAM1 замените на ваш параметр1
regular2 = re.findall(r'PARAM2=(\S+)', rf1)[0] #PARAM2 замените на ваш параметр2
new_text = rf2.replace('PARAM1', regular1).replace('PARAM2', regular2) #заменить PARAM1, PARAM2 на ваши параметры1,2
f2 = open("Путь к файлу 2.txt", "w") #Поменяйте на путь к файлу 2
f2.write(new_text)
f2.close()
```

Данный код предполагает, что в файле 1 после `value1` и после `value2` есть какой-нибудь знак табуляции. Это может быть перенос строки(т.е. PARAM1=value1 на отдельной строке), пробел, и т.д., что может говорить о конце данного value.

Answer (score 0):

Если поправить `PARAM1` на `${PARAM1}` в файле `example.txt`, то вариант такой:

```sh
export $(cat param.txt | xargs); envsubst < example.txt
```

Будет вывод в консоль. Если нужно в файл, то дописать `> output.txt`

Comment: `source param,txt` однако

Comment: @0andriy, так не будет работать, `envsubst` использует переменные окружения

Comment: Так я про первую часть. У вас `source param.txt`  именно это и сделает, положит содержимое в переменные окружения.

Comment: @0andriy, нет. `source param.txt ; env | grep PARAM1` - пусто. `export $(cat param.txt | xargs); env | grep PARAM1` - не пусто

Comment: А, ну понятно. Их вам ещё экспортировать надо. В варианте с `sed` всё будет работать, т.к. (смотрите за руками) `$ source params.txt 
$ echo $PARAM1
value1
$ echo $PARAM2
value2`